# Show and hide in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have tried to show and hide in jquery in onload but it have not shown 
could some one look and provide solution..i just done onclick of radio button listbox wants to display..Any ideas

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(window).load = function () {
  $("#main input[name='B']").click(function () {
    alert("hiiii");
    if ($('input[name=B]:checked').val() == "country") {
      alert("country");


      $("#country").show();
      $("#state,#city").hide();

    }
    if ($('input[name=B]:checked').val() == "state") {
      alert("state");

      $("#state").show();
      $("#country,#city").hide();

    }
    if ($('input[name=B]:checked').val() == "city") {
      alert("city");

      $("#city").show();
      $("#country,#state").hide();

    }
  });
</script>

</head>

<body>
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="2">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="B" value="country">
      </td>
      <td>Country</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="B" value="state">
      </td>
      <td>State</td>
      <td>
        <input type="radio" name="B" value="city">
      </td>
      <td>City</td>

    </tr>
  </table>

  Productline:
  <select id="productline">
    <option value="Motorcycles">Motorcycles</option>
    <option value="Planes">Planes</option>
    <option value="Ships">Ships</option>
    <option value="Trains">Trains</option>
  </select>
  <select id="country">
    <option value="Australia">Australia</option>
    <option value="Austria">Austria</option>
    <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
    <option value="Canada">Canada</option>
    <option value="Denmark">Denmark</option>
    <option value="Finland">Finland</option>
    <option value="France">France</option>
    <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
  </select>

  <select id="state">
    <option value="BC">BC</option>
    <option value="CA">CA</option>
    <option value="CT">CT</option>
    <option value="Isle&#32;of&#32;Wight">Isle&#32;of&#32;Wight</option>
    <option value="MA">MA</option>
    <option value="NH">NH</option>
    <option value="NJ">NJ</option>
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="NV">NV</option>
  </select>
  <select id="city">
    <option value="Allentown">Allentown</option>
    <option value="Århus">Århus</option>
    <option value="Auckland&#32;&#32;">Auckland&#32;&#32;</option>
    <option value="Barcelona">Barcelona</option>
    <option value="Bergamo">Bergamo</option>
    <option value="Bergen">Bergen</option>
    <option value="Boston">Boston</option>
    <option value="Bräcke">Bräcke</option>
    <option value="Brickhaven">Brickhaven</option>
    <option value="Bridgewater">Bridgewater</option>
    <option value="Brisbane">Brisbane</option>
    <option value="Bruxelles">Bruxelles</option>
  </select>

</body>
```

Comment: Something like this? http://jsbin.com/sekuzice/1/edit

Comment: You are using same condition `if($('input[name=B]:checked').val()=="country")` is it correct

Comment: onload  3 listbox wants to hide and onclick of radio button it  have to show

Comment: This code could be greatly reduced and cleaned up tremendously :x

Comment: please select an answer

Answer (score 1):

This is a wrong syntax:

```
$(window).load =function()
```

correct is:

```
$(window).load(function()
```

But my suggestion is to use it on `$(function(){});` document ready.

---

So you can try this:

add an id `#main` to your table:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="2" id="main">
   //-------------------------------here----------^^^^^^^^

$(function(){ // <----document ready function shorter version
    $("#main :radio").on('change', function(){ // <---apply change event
        $('#'+this.value).show(); //<---show the target
        if($(e.target).val() == 'country'){
           $('#'+this.value).siblings('select:not(#productline)').hide(); 
        } //--^----------------------------------^hide only if country is checked
    });
});
```

#### [Updated Demo @ Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75yLm/1/) as per comment suggested by *kenshin.thebattosai*

Comment: checkout the updated js code `$('#'+this.value).show().siblings('select').hide();` update this line.

Comment: LOL it's a nice idea, but this will also hide the other selects, which includes the product line select. Check out [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21901280/2081561). :)

Comment: @kenshin.thebattosai thanks for the suggestion and you are correct this should be like this as updated.

Comment: No you are missing the point. If you hide siblings, the Product select will also be hidden. Do you understand? select#productline is a direct sibling of type 'select'.

Comment: Yes, but now you have gone and hard-coded a value `#productline`. This is bad for development and scaling. If you need to add another select which is not to be affected, you will have to touch this JS code again. Instead, you can take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21901280/2081561) which has nothing hard-coded. You are not following the concept of 'separation of concerns' here. Also you will see that your JSFiddle isn't working as expected. LOL! For all this editing, you can let him take my answer instead.

Comment: why hide only if country is 'checked'? (And do we 'check' radio buttons, I wonder!? :D Nothing serious man)

Answer (score 0):

- You have no `#main` element
- `$(window).load =function() {` should be `$(window).load(function() {`
- you're missing `});`

http://jsbin.com/sekuzice/1/edit

Answer (score 0):

update the

> $(window).load to window.onload

and give the table an id attribute which you have assigned

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
 $(window).load(function(){
    $("input[name=B]").change(function(){
     if($('input[name=B]:checked').val()=="country")
     {
            alert("country");


            $("#country").show();
            $("#state,#city").hide();

     }
     if($('input[name=B]:checked').val()=="state")
     {
            alert("state");

            $("#state").show();
            $("#country,#city").hide();

     }
     if($('input[name=B]:checked').val()=="city")
     {
            alert("city");
            $("#city").show();
            $("#country,#state").hide();
     }
});
});
```

1. You have no #main element
2. $(window).load =function() { should be $(window).load(function() {
3. use $(document).ready(function () { instead of $(window).load(function() {

**ALTERNATE SOLUTION**

try to make your code simple

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $("input[name=B]").change(function(){
        var elem = "#" + $('input[name=B]:checked').val();
        if($(elem).length){
            $("#country,#state,#city").hide();
            $(elem).show();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$( document ).ready(function(e) {
    $("input[name=B]").click(function () {
        if ($('input[name=B]').is(':checked')) {
            var val =   $('input[name=B]:checked').val();
            switch(val){
                case "country":
                alert("country");
                $("#country").show();
                $("#state,#city").hide();
                break;

                case "state":
                alert("state");         
                $("#state").show();
                $("#country,#city").hide();
                break;

                case "city":
                alert("city");          
                $("#city").show();
                $("#country,#state").hide();
                break;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are complicating things while missing the power of jQuery.

You can simply change the input names to `location`, add a `data-choose="location"` attribute to the `select` elements you need to show or hide depending on the radio and write simpler and valid code **without hardcoding anything** like "state,"city", or "country" strings.

See [this](http://jsbin.com/sekuzice/11/edit?html,js,output).

This will be all the jQuery you need:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-choose="location"]').hide();
    $('[name="location"]').change(function () {
        $('[data-choose="location"]').hide();
        $('#'+$(this).val()).show();
    });
})
```

**EDIT:**
Changed `.click` to `.change` upon **[Jai](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059101/jai)**'s advice.

Comment: LOL! You should understand that what form elements use to have  which events

Comment: I suppose you're right. `.click` could be `.change`, no? Thanks! :) However, I don't think the selector should be `:radio` since that will create problems when OP tries adding another set of radio buttons somewhere else in his page. :)